# Neo4j DB - client connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, neo4j

I've got a question about getting control of query 'timeout'. What i want to achive is that i could control 'query timeout' - i want to set it let's say for 3 seconds and if query will take longer, i'll get an exception/whatever.

So far i was trying countless ways, even with overriding some api's to get to the Client within RestRequest to set it there... but i had no transaction controll.

I'm not posting any versions of components i've used/tried already, becouse it's not a big deal to change it. The only 1 restriction is java version 6.

Please, post some advices / approaches that i could use... becouse im out of ideas.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the transaction timeout in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` with this setting:

```
org.neo4j.server.transaction.timeout=NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_HERE
```

More info available in the docs [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configuration_parameters)

**Edit**

You can control timeout on a per query basis by enabling execution guard on the Neo4j server and adding a `max-execution-time` header to your request:

In `conf/neo4j-server.properties` set:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=MAX_POSSIBLE_MS_HERE
```

In `conf/neo4j.properties` set:

```
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

Then add header `max-execution-time=100` and the timeout for that query only will be 100ms.

More information available [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113461/how-to-set-read-timeout-per-query-using-java-rest-binding)

I just tested this against both the [legacy Cypher HTTP endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-cypher.html) and the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) for Neo4j 2.2.5.

Comment: Hello, yes i know that, but i also want to achieve controllable timeout from a client. To put is straight 1 time i want to have 3 seconds max to wait for response, other time i can wait 5 seconds... that's why i want to have full controll from client.

Comment: OK - I understand your question now. Thanks for clarifying. Check out my edit.

Comment: Thank You William ! I wasn't here for a while and i've accepted Your answer just now!
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

From what I tested (neo4j 2.2.2) it seems that you will need to set both of the following:

in `./conf/neo4j.properties`:

```
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

and in `./conf/neo4j-server.properties`:

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime={timeout_in_seconds}
```

(note: this number is in seconds, not milliseconds)

before a query specific timeout, added to the header of the request, will work.

```
`max-execution-time={timeout_in_milliseconds}`
```

Neo4j will use whichever timeout is shorter, so specify a large timeout in the property file.

Comment: Yes exactly, Thank You for help ;)